# What is the identity of the type?

Tags: haskell, math, monoids

I have following data type:

```
data Bull = Fools
  | Twoo
  deriving (Eq, Show)
```

and use Monoid to implement it:

```
instance Monoid Bull where
  mempty = Fools
  mappend _ _ = Fools
```

As you can see, `mempty` is the identity function the identity laws does not hold:

```
*Main> x = Twoo
*Main> mappend mempty x == x
```

What would be the identity of `Bull` type?
What is the identity of `Bool` type?

Comment: It depends on how would you like implement `mappend`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Short answer**: It **depends on the `mappend` function**.

> What would be the identity of `Bull` type? What is the identity of `Bool` type?

A type has **no "inherent" identity**, an *identity* element only exists *with respect to a binary function* (here `mappend`), like the [*Wikipedia article says*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_element):

> In mathematics, an identity element or neutral element is a special type of element of a set **with respect to a binary operation** on that set, which leaves other elements unchanged when combined with them.

So it depends on what opperation `mappend` is.

In case of `Bool` if we define `mappend = (&&)`, then the *identity* element is `mempty = True`. But if we pick `mappend = (||)`, then `mempty = False`.

Your `instance Moniod Bull` is **incorrect**. Since it cannot satisfy the property:

```
mappend mempty x = x
```

If we pick `Fools` as the `mempty = Fools`, then `mappend Fools Twoo` should be `Twoo`. And if we pick `mempty = Twoo`, then `mappend Twoo Twoo` is still not `Twoo`.

The point of a `Monoid` is that you have to design the *binary operator* carefully. Like the [Haskell documentation on `Monoid`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html) says, it should satisfy the following rues:

> ```
> mappend mempty x = x
>
> mappend x mempty = x
>
> mappend x (mappend y z) = mappend (mappend x y) z
>
> mconcat = foldr mappend mempty
> ```

These rules are not "invented" for Haskell: a *monoid* is a well known [algebraic structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid). Usually in mathematics, a monoid is denoted as a 3-tuple. For instance *(N, +, 0)* with *N* the set here (for instance the natural numbers), *+* the binary function, and *0* the identity element.

Answer (score 6):

This is a great question, and one that I have played with several times before. In fact, it was one of the first uses of [universe](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/universe) that I ever came up with, and I still think it's a neat one. So let me show you!

Here's the idea: we're going to use the universe package to enumerate *all* possible implementations of `mempty` and `mappend`, and then check which ones satisfy the laws. First, some boilerplate:

```
import Data.Universe
import Data.Universe.Instances.Reverse

data Bull = Fools | Twoo deriving (Bounded, Enum, Eq, Ord, Read, Show)
instance Universe Bull
instance Finite Bull
```

This just imports the appropriate bits of the package and defines your type. Now, let's code up the monoid laws. We want our `mappend` to be associative; writing `(+)` for `mappend`, we can demand:

```
associative        (+) = all (\(x,y,z) -> (x+y)+z == x+(y+z)) universe
```

The identity laws are very similar to each other, and connect our `mappend` to our `mempty` (which we'll call `(+)` and `zero` here):

```
leftIdentity  zero (+) = all (\x -> zero+x == x) universe
rightIdentity zero (+) = all (\x -> x+zero == x) universe
```

A monoid should satisfy all three laws:

```
monoid (zero, (+)) = associative (+) && leftIdentity zero (+) && rightIdentity zero (+)
```

And now we can construct the list of all monoids just by filtering out the ones that meet the laws:

```
monoidsOnBull :: [(Bull, Bull -> Bull -> Bull)]
monoidsOnBull = filter monoid universe
```

Let's check it in ghci:

```
> mapM_ print monoidsOnBull
(Twoo,[(Fools,[(Fools,Fools),(Twoo,Fools)]),(Twoo,[(Fools,Fools),(Twoo,Twoo)])])
(Fools,[(Fools,[(Fools,Fools),(Twoo,Twoo)]),(Twoo,[(Fools,Twoo),(Twoo,Fools)])])
(Twoo,[(Fools,[(Fools,Twoo),(Twoo,Fools)]),(Twoo,[(Fools,Fools),(Twoo,Twoo)])])
(Fools,[(Fools,[(Fools,Fools),(Twoo,Twoo)]),(Twoo,[(Fools,Twoo),(Twoo,Twoo)])])
```

(Aside: how should we read this output? Well, the universe package shows functions of type `a -> b` by showing its graph of type `[(a, b)]`, that is, lists of pairs of inputs and outputs. Each line of the above output is a tuple with a suitable `mempty` in the first part and a suitable `mappend` in the second part.)

So what do these monoids *do*? Let's take them one at a time:

```
(Twoo,[(Fools,[(Fools,Fools),(Twoo,Fools)]),(Twoo,[(Fools,Fools),(Twoo,Twoo)])])
```

Here the `mappend` outputs `Fools` unless both inputs are `Twoo`. That is, this is the `Bull` equivalent of `(&&)`. The identity for `(&&)` is `True` -- or `Twoo`, in `Bull`'s case.

```
(Fools,[(Fools,[(Fools,Fools),(Twoo,Twoo)]),(Twoo,[(Fools,Twoo),(Twoo,Fools)])])
```

This `mappend` outputs `Fools` if its two inputs are equal, and `Twoo` otherwise. You can think of this as kind of like xor on `Bool`, or two's complement addition on 1-bit numbers. Its identity is `Fools` (or zero).

```
(Twoo,[(Fools,[(Fools,Twoo),(Twoo,Fools)]),(Twoo,[(Fools,Fools),(Twoo,Twoo)])])
```

This one is just like the last one, but negated everywhere.

```
(Fools,[(Fools,[(Fools,Fools),(Twoo,Twoo)]),(Twoo,[(Fools,Twoo),(Twoo,Twoo)])])
```

This one is just like the first one, but negated everywhere. It also happens to be just like `(||)` on `Bool`, which has identity `False`.

This ends the lecture, but there are two other fun notes worth adding.

First, `base` offers the [`All`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:All) and [`Any`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Any) monoids for when you want your `mappend` to be `(&&)` and `(||)`, respectively. As far as I know, there isn't a suitable newtype to get xor or its negation as a `Monoid`; but you can fake it by declaring a `Num` instance for `Bool` (using the `Word1` intuition that `False` is 0 and `True` is 1) to get it via `Sum Bool`.

And second, another answer here asks: what monoid is there for `data Color = Red | Green | Blue`? We have all the machinery to answer that question now and affirm that there are in fact quite a few monoids:

```
> length monoidsOnColor
33
```

I encourage you to try to construct the code that will list them all and poke through them to see what insights you can gain!

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a single monoid for a given set (or type, in Haskell). In fact, the identity in a monoid is not determined by the set on which it is defined, but rather by the operation (which is called `mappend` in Haskell). For example, a monoid on integers could be defined on addition (with identity `0`) or on product (with identity `1`).

This is why the [`Sum`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#v:Sum) and the [`Product`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#v:Product) types exist: since there are multiple possible implementation of the `Monoid` typeclass on the set of `Num a => a`, we prefer to wrap it into a `newtype` and define the `Monoid` implementation on the wrapped type.

There are similar constructs for the `Bool` type, with [`All`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:All) , monoid on booleans under conjuction (`(&&)`) with identity `True`, and [`Any`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Any) , monoid on booleans under disjunction (`(||)`) with identity `False`. In fact, booleans can form monoids on lots of other operations (e.g. XOR and XNOR gates).

Since the `Bull` type is isomorphic to the `Bool` type (both have exactly two nullary constructors), you can inspire yourself from the implementations of `Monoid` on `Bool`, but we cannot decide which implementation fits best in your case with further context.

Also, as Anton Xue mentionned, even if you *could* define a monoid for `Bull`, does it really make sense ? What is your type supposed to represent?

Comment: It is just a show case from the haskellbook. Thanks for answer.